# YugabyteDB 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: wsl-2, ubuntu-22.04, yugabytedb

I follow the [YugabyteDB Quickstart](https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/quick-start/linux/). I am using WSL2 with Ubuntu 22.04.2.

After using the command `./bin/yugabyted start` I get following exception:

```
yugabyted crashed. For troubleshooting, contact us on https://www.yugabyte.com/slack or check our FAQ at https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/faq/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/f/Yugabyte/yugabyte-2.19.0.0/./bin/yugabyted", line 3699, in run
    args.func()
  File "/mnt/f/Yugabyte/yugabyte-2.19.0.0/./bin/yugabyted", line 399, in start
    self.start_processes()
  File "/mnt/f/Yugabyte/yugabyte-2.19.0.0/./bin/yugabyted", line 1450, in start_processes
    prereqs_check_result = self.prereqs_check(ulimits=ulimits_failed)
  File "/mnt/f/Yugabyte/yugabyte-2.19.0.0/./bin/yugabyted", line 1108, in prereqs_check
    check = self.linux_prereqs_check()
  File "/mnt/f/Yugabyte/yugabyte-2.19.0.0/./bin/yugabyted", line 1080, in linux_prereqs_check
    transparent_hugepages = re.search("\[(.*)\]", transparent_hugepages_check[0]).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Before this exception is thrown, in logs there are two errors:

```
[yugabyted start] 2023-07-22 10:19:36,756 ERROR:  | 0.0s | Error changing RLIMIT_NOFILE from 1024 to 1048576: current limit exceeds maximum limit
[yugabyted start] 2023-07-22 10:19:36,756 ERROR:  | 0.0s | Error changing RLIMIT_NPROC from 7823 to 12000: current limit exceeds maximum limit
```

If I think good, the problem is with this python line:

```
transparent_hugepages = re.search("\[(.*)\]", transparent_hugepages_check[0]).group(1)
```

The `search` function returns `None`, so probably I don't have `transparent hugepages`? What does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have uninstalled WSL2 and then installed it using: `wsl --install -d Ubuntu-22.04` and it works.

Comment: > AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'


The error is related to missing transparent pages support. The python script didn't expect "null" as a value. You can either run the db manually. Or you can upgrade at a release after this commit https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/commit/978ab610ec98e223063597ea662062b4e312cf48 (2.19.3+ should work)

The upgrade you did probably just exposed the "transparent_pages" flag and launcher script didn't error.